# Yii addForeignKey not added to mysql table indexes

Tags: yii, migration

I used addForeignKey() method to add two foreign keys. Both keys added but only one shows in Table Indexs (mysql)

Comment: How did you add these FK and how did you check that one is missing?

Comment: $this->addForeignKey(
            'FK_user_business_location',
            'business_location',
            'user_id',
            'user',
            'id',
            'RESTRICT',
            'CASCADE'
        );

After run I checked using HeidiSql

Comment: When using addForeignKey() method in Yii migrations it only adding the foreign kyes not Indexes .. To add indexes use $this->createIndex('keyName' , 'Table' , 'Column name')

Answer (score 0):

When using `addForeignKey()` method in Yii migrations it only adding the foreign keys not indexes.
To add indexes use `$this->createIndex('keyName' , 'Table' , 'Column name')`